# Custom string in rails 4 active records error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an activerecords error message defined in yml file as:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        participant:
          attributes:
            base:
              file_type_invalid: This file type %{file_name} is not acceptable
```

So the error message should comes out as `This file type xyz.zip is not acceptable`

and in the corresponding model, I add error as follows for such error:

`errors.add(:base, :file_type_invalid)`
here how can i pass file_name to the error message? This does not work

`errors.add(:base, :file_type_invalid, file_name: 'xyz.zip')`

So how to solve this issue? Please note `file_name` is not an attribute or value of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use I18n directly for that:

```
errors.add(:base, I18n.translate('activerecord.errors.models.participant.attributes.base.file_type_invalid', file_name: 'some filename'))
```

It sort of defeats the purpose of auto lookup, but as far as I know the `add` method doesn't support arguments for an error string.